# How many concurrent call can SharePoint online accept without being throttled?

Tags: azure-functions, sharepoint-online

I am moving around documents to SharePoint online using azure function.
I am running 10 parallel instances of azure function. That doesn't give me any throttle issues but it's really slow.
Any idea how many concurrent calls can SharePoint accept without being throttled?

Answer (score 0):

A single function app only scales out to a maximum of 200 instances. A single instance may process more than one message or request at a time though, so there isn't a set limit on number of concurrent executions. You can specify a lower maximum to throttle scale as required.

More info:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/event-driven-scaling

Comment: Do you know what that lower maximum could be so that I Don't get throttled by SharePoint online?

Comment: Below 99 instance depend on function complexity and maybe database response and other parameters , for more instance you need Premium plan and you can specify a lower maximum for a specific app by modifying the **functionAppScaleLimit** value config.